# List<int> is not a subclass of 'IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to determine some object is derived from `IEnumerable`, but Reflection says `List<int>` is not a subclass of `IEnumerable`.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/an1n62

```
var a = new List<int>();

// true
Console.WriteLine(a is IEnumerable);

// falsa
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEnumerable)));
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEnumerable<>)));
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEnumerable<int>)));
```

`is` keyword works find, but I have to sovle this without the keyword.

Comment: `IsAssignableFrom`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want, you need to use `IsAssignableFrom`:

```
typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(a.GetType())
```

The [documentation for IsSubclassOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.issubclassof?view=netframework-4.7.2) explicitly states this:

> The IsSubclassOf method cannot be used to determine whether an
>   interface derives from another interface, or whether a class
>   implements an interface. Use the IsAssignableFrom method for that
>   purpose.